# Конфликт версий базы данных Sqlite

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, android-sqlite

Здравствуйте, создаю базу данных, данные которой заполняю с облачного хранилища.

В классе Database происходит чтение и запись данных в sqlite.
Проверяю подключение к интернету и делаю апгрейд.

//options.getVersion - версия базы в облаке

```
 mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context,"mydatabase.db",null, options.getVersion());

                    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(mDatabaseHelper.OPTIONS_COLUMN_MAP, options.getMap());
                        values.put(mDatabaseHelper.OPTIONS_COLUMN_VERSION, options.getVersion());
                        mSqLiteDatabase.insert(mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_OPTIONS, null, values);
```

Далее мне надо в каком-нибудь фрагменте произвести запрос. К примеру:

```
         mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context,"mydatabase.db",null, ??????); // здесь проблема

        mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView4);


    Cursor c = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM options", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        textView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(mDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ABOUT)));
    }
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю какую мне указывать версию в конструкторе. options.version будет равна нулю при недоступности облака.

Ошибка: Can't downgrade database from version 25 to 1

Или возможно я вообще неправильно организую чтение базы в фрагменте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При чтении из фрагмента, согласно Вашему коду, Вы должны обращаться к своей локальной базе. Версия БД в данном случае определяется Вами. Т.е. к версии БД она не имеет никакого отношения. 
Таким образом, при открытии вашей локальной БД хэлпером воспользуйтесь конструктором:

```
mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Если меняются данные в БД, то версию менять не стоит. Версию БД следует менять в том случае, когда будет изменена ее структура, а так как Ваша БД зависит от облачной БД, то соответственно вы свою БД поменяете, когда изменится БД в облаке.  При этом Вам надо будет переопределить в вашем классе хелпере метод onUpgrade.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! я почему-то думал, что для обновления данных базы нужно указывать новую версию)

Comment: @andreipiletsky не за что) нет, при обновлении данных, версия БД не меняется. Если мы решили Ваш вопрос, отметьте его как решенный и полезный